# Populating a ListView with data from Parse.com

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I'm trying to populate my ListView with data retrieved from Parse.com using the `findInBackground` method. My list is not being populated and I know the culprit is this background method, but I don't know of a solution.

Code:

```
private void getData() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyParseTable");
    query.whereEqualTo("users", currentUser);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            list = new ArrayList<ExampleClass>();
            for(ParseObject result : parseObjects){
                ExampleClass g = new ExampleClass();
                g.setName(result.getString("name"));
                list.add(g);

            }
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

I basically use this method shown above in the adapter constructor to populate the ArrayList. I added the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but that didn't help. What is the correct way of populating a listview with Parse.com data?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create arraylist inside callback method:

```
list = new ArrayList<ExampleClass>();
```

But pass it to adapter